# Can I use the same Firebase for two different Apps?

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'd like to use the same Firebase for two apps. In both apps the users should be able to login via Google, Facebook or E-Mail.

But in the "Login & Auth" section of my Firebase dashboard I can only add one Facebook App Id. And in the Facebook Developer settings of that app I can only add one packagename.

That's a problem for me because the packagename needs to be unique on the Google Play Store.

Is there a way to enable users to log in to the same Firebase but from two different apps?

Comment: Cross-post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/RpcsCN0vL0Q

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firebase employee here.

We have a one Firebase database per app policy. However, you can still use the same Firebase database for admin and dashboard apps.

Comment: Is this still true for Firebase 9.0.0? For me it looks like you can now e.g. add two Android apps into one project.

Comment: I just stumbled across this Q&A, and the Firebase Console offers the ablitily to register multiple apps. So maybe this answer is no longer valid, considering the fact that it is 3 years old. An update would be appropiate.

Comment: @DanielF
where in the firebase console can you register multiple apps?  i happen to be looking for this and can't find it

Comment: There's a settings-wheel to the right of "Overview" (upper left corner below "Firebase"). Click on "Project settings", then you'll see it.

Comment: as @DanielF says, Overview -> Settings -> General, Scroll down to Your apps - > Add App

Comment: @David East  Is there any update for IOS apps or same rule applies?