# Two Android apps and one Firebase database

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to use one Firebase database for two Android apps. One app will have write access to database and another will have read access to database. These two apps have to be separated. I can't merge them. Can I use one Firebase database for two apps? How? Please guide step by step. I am new to Firebase.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to have 1 Firebase database for 2 apps with different package names?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37390095/is-there-a-way-to-have-1-firebase-database-for-2-apps-with-different-package-nam)

Comment: Thank you for the reply... It's helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well from what I know you can add as many apps as you want for you'r project,just press add app on the `FirebaseConsole`.
You can use different package name  or signing key

Comment: Thank you for the reply... It's helpful