# How do i use the same firebase database for two apps?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am not understanding how to use same database for 2 apps. The second app would retrieve the data from the database and display the data order by the customers to the salesmen. The second app is used by the salesmen and the first app is used by customers.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37874920/can-multiple-android-application-access-same-firebase-database, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37390095/is-there-a-way-to-have-1-firebase-database-for-2-apps-with-different-package-nam, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38108406/two-android-apps-and-one-firebase-database

Answer (score 11):

Yes you can do that! You can register more than 1 Android application for 1 Firebase project.

1. Go to Firebase console
2. Go to your project
3. In Project overview, click "Add another app"
4. Set up the app just like how you set the previous app

That way, you can have 2 Firebase app accessing the same Firebase infrastructure such as, Functions, Database, Firestore, Storage.