# how to make one back-end and database for two android apps

Tags: java, android, firebase

I want to make two android apps with java one for the buyer and one for the seller each one has its front-end but they share the same back-end and database, and I want to add the feature that allows buyers to communicate with the seller using realtime message, is there a way to implement this or it is impossible?

Comment: Yes, that's possible and a lot of applications work like this. Build 2 Android apps, communicate over REST with the backend and use Google Firebase for push notifications.

Comment: How do you think the eBay app works?

Comment: the seller posts a product with many plans for one item or many items with reduction ex: many buyers want to buy the same product for getting a reduction so they  contact the sellers using real-time message and arrange an appointment in seller's store and pay with cash (there is no e-commerce payment )

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. You can add as many apps as you want for your project

See these answers [Answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37896483/7765316), [Answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38110834/7765316)

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37874920/7765316)

Comment: what about real-time messages can a user from one app send a message to a user from the other app?

Comment: yes it is possible,one database can sync with many applications