# 2 different android apps in 1 Firebase Project

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[Image.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgV6Y.png)
> I have a Client app and Driver app under 1 Firebase Project.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37390095/is-there-a-way-to-have-1-firebase-database-for-2-apps-with-different-package-nam) is only said yes it can be done, but how can it be done?? not stated

- Two different `google-services.json`
- One `Firebase Database` for both
- When from Customer app order is made, it is saving to Database as a `child("Orders")`, and as a test, I can retrieve those `Orders` in Customer app.

**But how to retrieve those `Orders`** in Driver app??

This is a piece of code, in Driver app which tries to retrieve data from Customer app.

```
final DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Orders");

    final ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                String surname = ds.child("surname").getValue(String.class);
                String beverages = ds.child("beverages").getValue(String.class);
                String deserts = ds.child("deserts").getValue(String.class);
                String time = ds.child("time").getValue(String.class);

                edtx_name.setText(name);
                edtx_surname.setText(surname);
                edtx_beverages.setText(beverages);
                edtx_deserts.setText(deserts);
                edtx_time.setText(time);

                Log.d("Test", "" + edtx_name + "/" + edtx_surname + "/" + edtx_beverages + "/" + edtx_deserts + "/" + edtx_time);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    };
    rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

But this doesnt retrieve. what am i making wrong?

Comment: How should we know, you might consider adding information about your database?

Comment: Sorry? can you explain in a more detail what you are saying?

Comment: How would you expect anyone to know how to solve your problem from your data given? We do not know anything about your database or Firebase project.

Comment: 1 DB, 1 child object called "Orders" . inside "Orders" I have set .push() to generate random unique keys. I have set value to those edittexts such as name, surname, beverages........ If client fills edittexts, the data is saved in the firebase project. I can see that. But, how should i retrieve that data from my driver app. anything else you should know?

Comment: I have uploaded an image bro.