# Problem in connecting second app to firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When I connect my second Android app to firebase, after sometime it shows **process unexpectedly exit** this error. Please suggest me tips for **how to configure multiple projects for same database.** Because one app is retrieving data and another was upload the data.

I never done before like this. Now I developed two different apps. One to show data and one to upload data. But when I connect with firebase second app shows `error` and this was `process unexpectedly exit`. I don't know why it is coming and where.

So please help me. If do you have any tips or suggestion for me please suggest. Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37390095/is-there-a-way-to-have-1-firebase-database-for-2-apps-with-different-package-nam This answer should help your problem

Answer (score 0):

Go to your firebase console, then click on `Project settings`:

[image: Project settings]

After click on `Add App`:

[image: Add your second project]

And finally, download the `google-service` file in your second application.

Comment: I make changes but app shows process unexpectedly exit, even I changed SDK version  and gradle dependency version,